# Numerical Solution to following 2nd order ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

We have the following IVP for $w\in C^3(0,0.5)$:
$$\begin{cases}w'''(t)+w''(t)=e^t+1 \\ w(0)=1; w'(0)=0; w''(0)=1\end{cases}.$$

The question is to do an appropriate change of variable so that we get 3 first order IVPs which we know how to solve numerically.

**My Try:** If we use the change of variable $v(t)\to w''(t)$, we get the following first order system:
$$\begin{cases}v'(t)+v(t)=e^t+1 \\ v(0)=1\end{cases}.$$

The given system then gives us an approximation of $v$ using rudimentary  methods (Runge-Kutta). Now,  this is only one 1st order system. **The question asks for two more; what are they?**

Comment: You also get $w'=u$ and $u'=v$, with the appropriate initial conditions.

Comment: @LutzL these two changes of variables wont yield 1st order systems.

Comment: No, they are the additional components for the full first order system for the 3D vector $(w,u,v)$. Could be a tree-forest problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\boldsymbol{y} := (w,w',w'')^{\top}$, then you obtain from the ODE:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{y}' = \left( \begin{array}{c}
w'\\
w''\\
w'''
\end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
w'\\
w''\\
-w'' + e^t + 1
\end{array}
\right) =: \boldsymbol{f}(t,\boldsymbol{y}),
\end{equation}
and from the given initial conditions:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{y}(0) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
w(0)\\
w'(0)\\
w''(0)
\end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1
\end{array}
\right) =: \boldsymbol{y}_0.
\end{equation}
You now have an initial-value problem in the standard form: $\boldsymbol{y}' = \boldsymbol{f}(t,\boldsymbol{y})$, $\boldsymbol{y}(0) = \boldsymbol{y}_0$, which you can solve numerically using a Runge-Kutta method.